# Findout output voltage of an opamp when given input voltage and open loop gain

Tags: operational-amplifier

Just in theory, please ignore the values...

Given the open loop gain of an opamp and its input voltage and a circuit similar to the figure below, how would I find the output voltage?

[image: opamp circuit]([![CircuitLab Schematic b3e6ns]([![CircuitLab Schematic p5y8pf]]

My thoughts were to just do nodal analysis and avoid the open loop gain all together since the circuit given is closed loop, I thought that it was irrelevant and just given to throw you off.
Or would the correct steps be to assume:
v_out = A(v_+ - v_-)
v_out = A(-v_-)

Comment: Use ideal OpAmp assumptions.

Comment: @NickAlexeev So then we would assume v+ = v-, and A = inf. And we would just find v_out using nodal analysis... right?

Comment: There is also the second ideal opamp assumption: *The inputs of the ideal OpAmp draw no current*.  You are on the right track, though.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Nice. Ok, yeah I am familiar with the assumptions for an ideal opamp, I was just curious about the assumption of what to do with the open loop gain. Like I said, I thought we should ignore that since our circuit is close loop (i.e. we have feedback). Thanks

Comment: The schematic doesn't show any op amps. Did you make changes to it in CircuitLab after posting the question?

Comment: @scanny yeah I did, I'll edit it right now.

Comment: @scanny fixed it. But the values and stuff don't matter. I am just curious as to whether the open loop gain matters for finding v_out given a closed loop circuit such as that

Comment: Open loop gain can certainly be used in the manner you have suggested. You will find that the output voltage is slightly different than for an infinite gain model. Because you cant assume v+ = v-, you have another unknown value. But you also have another equation so its all good

Comment: The situation is clear: Of course, the result is more exact if you consider the finite open-loop gain of the opamp. That means: Of course, it matters. However, it is up to you to decide, if this small improvement in correctness matters with respect tro your specific application and with respect to all other uncertainties and tolerances within the circuit. Assuming an ideal amplifier is always a simplification - but in most cases it makes sense and is good engineering practice.

Comment: Why not simplify your schematic first before throwing formulas at it ? The current into an opamp's input is ... so you can remove R.. because it does nothing. There are 2 resistors in parallel, combine them to one resistor. The text of V1 and R1 are on top of eachother, that's sloppy, fix it. Now there are only 2 resistors, a voltage source and an opamp left in a very standard configuration.

Comment: Yes - and for finding the output voltage you CAN use Harold Black`s famous formula for closed-loop gain (finite Aol). If you want to be as exact as possible use a lowpass function for the open-loop gain Aol(s).

Answer (score 2):

**Answer reformulated:**

As already noted, your circuit simplifies to:
[image]

When you close the loop the open-loop gain is reduced to the ratio \$ \frac{\text R2}{\text R1}\$ so, since it's an inverting amplifier, the output voltage becomes:
\$\ \ \text {Vout} = \ \ - \frac {\text R2}{\text R1} \times \text{Vin} \$